# Finding Relationship between Categorical and Continuous data

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, categorical-data, many-categories, pandas

A subset of my dataset looks as follows where cells in "cat1_ids" column contains list of "cat1" categories and cells in "person_id_list" column contains list of persons id. There are 2000 "cat1" categories and 1500 person, How to prove "no_of_days" is related to to these two columns? 
After proving a relationship exists the next step is to train a model on this data for predicting "no_of_days". Any suggestions on how to deal with cells containing tuple of values and make a model on it?
(both graphical and statistical methods would be appreciated for proving relationship)

```
  cat1_ids    person_id_list   no_of_days
0   (602,)        (12713,)        1.727083
4   (3, 131)      (12408,)        1.770833
5   (13,)         (12404,)        0.592361
6   (442,)        (12327,)        2.518750
7   (761,)        (12720,)        7.601389

shape => 75000x3
```

Which model should i use to train over this data to make prediction for no_of_days?

Edit:
    combinations of cat1_ids has greater influence on no_of_days as compared to person_id_list (it's domain knowledge). Max length of cat_ids and person_id_list is 8.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Do person IDs occur multiple times? If so, you can model this relationship with a mixed model (specifically, a repeated measures ANOVA).

Comment: Same person ID must appear several times as well as a category, because there are 1500 person IDs and 2000 categories and 75000 observations (last line of the printout: "format => 75000x3"). You can also change categories and person IDs to frequencies and then try to find a relationship for example: more frequently occurring person has higher no_of_days on average. For prediction, you get person ID, count how many times it occurs in your database and predict no_of_days accordingly.

Comment: Because you have tuples, you could aggregate frequencies in some way (e.g. sum them up) for a start.

Comment: both cat1_ids and person_id appear in multiple cells

Answer (score 1):

Since you have repeated measures, you can model this using a random effect, calculating a random offset from the overall intercept for individuals by estimating their variance. This is simple in the R package `lme4`:

```
LMM <- lmer(no_of_days ~ cat1ids + (1 | person_id_list))
summary(LMM)
```

After that you could bootstrap confidence intervals for the estimates, although that might take a while with that many observations. Note that this model assumes residual normality, so you may need to transform your response variable, or use a different error distribution in the context of a GLMM.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a repeated measures ANOVA. Like Frans Rodenburg suggested. 
This has two reasons: 
       1. it is easy to implement
       2. it is designed for related, not independent groups